# What is the proper way to edit items in a listview when using Kendo UI Mobile & MVVM?

Tags: kendo-ui

What is the proper way to edit items in a listview when using **Kendo UI Mobile** & **MVVM**?

I don't get the expected results when using the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="itemsView"
    data-role="view"
    data-model="vm">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: items" 
                             data-template="itemsTemplate">
    </ul>
    <script id="itemsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
        #=Name#
    </li>
    </script>

    <input type="text" data-bind="value: newValue" />
    <button data-role="button" data-bind="click: update">update</button>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
    items: [{
        Name: "Item1"}],
    newValue: '',
    update: function(e) {
        var item = this.get("items")[0];
        item.set("Name", this.get("newValue"));
        //adding the follwoing line makes it work as expected
        kendo.bind($('#itemsView'), vm);
    }
});

kendoApp = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
transition: "slide"});​
```

I expect the listview to reflect the change to the Name property of that item.  Instead, a new item is added to the listview.  Examining the array reveals that there is no additional item, and that the change was made.  (re)Binding the view to the view-model updates the list to reflect the change.  Re-Binding after a change like this doesn't seem to make any sense.

**Here is the jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5aCYp/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the `<li>` in the template.  The widget already supplies the `<li>` so the additional `<li>` messes up the rendering.  This question was answered by Petyo in the [kendo ui forums](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mobile/listview/proper-way-to-edit-items-in-a-listview-when-using-kendo-ui-mobile-mvvm.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question properly: but this is how I did something similar with Kendo Web UI, I expect mobile is not so different from Web UI from API perspective.

```
   $element.kendoListView({
        dataSource: list,
        template: idt,
        editTemplate: iet,
        autoBind: true
    });
```

The way I bind the listview is different, but I guess you can get similar results with your method as well.

I pass two templates to the list view, one for displaying and one for editing.
Display template contains a button (or any element) with css class `k-edit` to which kendo will automatically bind the listview edit action.

display template:

```
     <div class="item">
        # if (city) { #
            #: city #<br />
        # } #
        # if (postCode) { #
            #: postCode #<br />
        # } #
         <div class="btn">
            <a href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span>Edit</a>
            <a href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span>Delete</a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Edit template

```
     <div class="item editable">
        <div>City</div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: city" name="city" required="required" validationmessage="*" />
             <span data-for="city" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
         </div>
        <div>Post Code</div>
        <div>
             <input type="text" data-bind="value: postCode" name="postCode" required="required" validationmessage="*" />
             <span data-for="postCode" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="btn">
             <a href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-update"></span>Save</a>
             <a href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-cancel"></span>Cancel</a>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Clicking that element will put the current element on edit mode using the editTemplate.

Then on the editTemplate there is another button with `k-update` class, again to which kendo will automatically bind and call the save method on the data source.

Hopefully this will give you more ideas on how to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks but my situation is different because I'm using MVVM.  I've updated the question with a clearer code example and I also created a jsfiddle.